# Should I remove merged branches?

Tags: git

I wanted to start working on 'feature a', so I created a new branch `git checkout -b feature-a`. When the feature was finished and working correctly, I merged it in master `git checkout master; git merge feature-a`.

The problem is that now `git branch` still shows 'feature-a', which I don't want beacause I think this will soon become a mess, the list will bee too long.

Is there a way to remove it from the list? Should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete the unwanted local branch with `git branch -d feature-a`

Preferable to delete unwanted local branches to avoid clutter.

Comment: I'm reading your edit. I usually merge with the changeset hash `git merge changeset123`. Does `git merge feature-a` do the same?

Comment: Yup. `git merge feature-a` merges all the additional commits in the `featue-a` branch to `master`. Since feature branch is created with the purpose of adding a specific functionality, I usually merge it fully into the master, and not work on specific commits.

Comment: `-d` only deletes a branch which Git can detect is merged, use `-D` if it refuses to delete the branch. But!, make sure thechanges you have worked on are merged before you delete the branch ;)

Comment: @MindTooth Whoa, nice to know

Comment: To delete remotely use `git push origin :feature-a`