# Should you remove unused git branches?

Tags: git, optimization

Except for readability and clutter issues, should you remove git branches that will probably never be used again ?
Does it improve git performance or has any effect on the total size of your repository ?

It's not a duplicate of [Should I remove merged branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157734/should-i-remove-merged-branches) because I don't want to know how to remove git branches, but only, **why** I **should** delete them.

Comment: Branches are just pointers to specific commits. I cannot image that keeping has any performance impact.

Comment: @FelixKling: Indeed. However, if it's a pointer to a set of commits that has no other reference, then deleting that branch will allow Git to perform garbage collection (thus reducing storage/transfer requirements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unused branches contains changes and commits so they concur to the total size of your database.

When you delete a branch and the branch is not referenced anywhere else in the repository (for example there isn't a tag pointing to it), then git will be able to release the space used by the changes stored in the branch (immediately or after a garbage collection).

Whether you should remove the unused branches or not depends on whether you care to keep unused code around. If space is an issue, then you may want to delete them.

If space is not an issue, then you can keep them around as much as you want.

I personally delete unused branches because I don't like to have them around unless I don't need them for the following reasons:

1. They use space
2. They slow down maintenance operations (such as repository backups)
3. I create/delete branches quite often and if I don't delete them my branch list will become large enough to be unreadable in a few weeks

I believe it's important to mention that if the branch is merged into master or it is contained in another branch (actually, master itself is a branch) then deleting it will not allow you reclaim the space. This is because 3 branches pointing to the same references use exactly the same amount of space (except for the very limited space required to save the branch metadata).

Comment: I'm sure OP is talking about branches that are merged into reachable branches (ie `master` or some others)

Comment: "I personally delete unused branches ... They use space" --- so you create a code that isn't going to be used anywhere that often?

Comment: Yep @zerkms ! If, the branch is merged, the commits aren't saved twice so deleting one branch won't change anything, is it ? It's like if you had two references on the same variable.

Comment: @zerkms I have access on hundreds of repositories and usually never work on master, I switch to a branch for every single edit. So yes, it happens I make some edits and then I discard them. Also, if the branch is merged, I don't need the branch anymore.

Comment: @Simone Carletti: if the code is merged into master (or some other "persistent" branch) removing a branch **WON'T** change repository size in any sensible manner. So I'm quite confused about space argument

Comment: @zerkms That's correct. Actually, with "unused" branches I was referring to branches not merged into master. Because I agree that the definition of "unused" can be subjective, I've updated the answer to distinguish between unused and merged/referenced vs unused and not merged/referenced. I hope this clarifies my answer.

Comment: @Simone Carletti: yep it does. Though I barely can imagine a person who will keep some branch that is known to be useless at this moment and not dropping it without a good reason ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to delete branches that are not used any more. It helps developers by not cluttering the repository with branches which no one use, and it helps git, by clearing space used by the branches. This also makes git clone and some other operations more faster.